# Java Wildcard writing and reading permissions

Tags: java, generics, wildcard, bounded-wildcard

When learning about Java Wildcards i found myself misunderstanding about this theme, so.

1. **`Upper Bound`** allows me to read-only members of generic class
2. **`Lower Bound`** allows me to write to member, but only if it is the types lower bound

```
List<? extends Vehicle> vehicleList = new ArrayList<Car>(); 
vehicleList.add(new Scooter()); // Compile-time Error!
```

Compiler won't let us write anything here, because he can't ensure that elements of list would be the correct type (for later reading).

```
List<? super Car> carList = new ArrayList<Car>();
carList.add(new Car()); // Ok
carList.add(new Vehicle()); // Compile-time Error
```

This happens because compiler can ensure that **lowest type** is always Car. And then we can pass it only **Car**.
Am I right?

Comment: Yes; this is called co-/contra-variance.

Answer (score 4):

You are basically right.

- `List<? extends Vehicle>` should be thought of as a **list of an unknown subclass of Vehicle** (including Vehicle itself).

  As such, nothing can be inserted safely into it (except `null`).

  When reading from the list, its objects can safely be assigned to `Vehicle`.
- Conversely, `List<? super Vehicle>` is a **list of an unknown superclass of Vehicle** (including Vehicle).

  Every subclass of `Vehicle` can be safely inserted into it.

  When reading from the list, its objects can only be assigned to `Object`.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that `List<? super Car>` is an abstract type.  Think about the actual concrete class of an object of this type.  All of these are possibilities, and obviously there are others.

- ArrayList <Car>
- ArrayList <Vehicle>
- ArrayList <Object>
- LinkedList <Car>
- LinkedList <Vehicle>
- LinkedList <Object>

Now, since `ArrayList<Car>` and `LinkedList<Car>` don't allow the addition of an object whose class is `Vehicle`, the compiler can't let you write `carList.add(new Vehicle())` if `carList` is of type `List<? super Car>`.